# How to get a list of dashboards through azure-devops-python-api

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get a list of dashboards using [azure-devops-python-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api).
I can't figure out how to connect the libraries correctly to get the list of dashboards and work with them.
What I've done is this:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v6_0 import DashboardClient 
import pprint
import requests
import json

personal_access_token = 'PAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/Orgname/'
team_context = 'Orgname'
# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

dashboard_resp = DashboardClient(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
dashboards = dashboard_resp.get_dashboards_by_project('', team_context)
```

When I try to execute this code, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "az-dev-dash.py", line 16, in <module>
    dashboard_resp = azure.DashboardClient(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
AttributeError: module 'azure.devops.v6_0' has no attribute 'DashboardClient'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below Python script to list the dashboards in a particular project using python.

**Here is the python code:**

```html
from re import T
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v6_0.dashboard.models import Dashboard, TeamContext
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v6_0.dashboard.dashboard_client import DashboardClient 
import pprint
import requests
import json

personal_access_token = '<PATToken>'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<OrgnName>' ##OrganisationalUrl

team_context=TeamContext('<projectName>')

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
dashboard_resp = DashboardClient(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
dashboards = dashboard_resp.get_dashboards_by_project(team_context)
for item in dashboards:
 print(item)
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/Dashboards/List?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Rest API, to `list the dashboards in the project`.

Comment: I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "az-dev-dash.py", line 20, in <module>
    dashboards = dashboard_resp.get_dashboards_by_project(team_context)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/azure/devops/v6_0/dashboard/dashboard_client.py", line 131, in get_dashboards_by_project
    if team_context.project_id:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'project_id'

Comment: How do you determine team_context variable?

Comment: As Mentioned  in the above code, you need to pass the respective project name as parameter to the `TeamContext()`  & appened to that `team_context` variable `team_context=TeamContext('<projectName>')`

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Hey @VenkateshDodda-MSFT, can u suggest how to upload this json to azure devops dahsboard? I mean my requirement is to take a backup..and upload this dashboard information to the UI later on

Comment: This code worked for me. But I am confused about the connection. The code creates variable core_client, but this connection is never used in the code. How is the call to DashboardClient associated with the connection?